# Custom array with key and value pair from array of objects

Tags: javascript

Trying to construct a key, value pair based on the array of objects data.

**Snippet**

```js
const cars = [{
  car: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}];

const result = cars.map((val) => `${val.car}|${val.year}`)

console.log(result)
```

The result I'm expecting is below. Could anyone please help?

```
[{cars: [{ car: 'BMW', year: '2020'}], key: 'BMW|2020'}]
```

Comment: Is it important that `cars` (in the result you've provided) is an array `[]`, rather than just an object `{}`?

Comment: did you mean this `res = [{'cars': cars, 'key': cars.map((val) => `${val.car}|${val.year}`)[0]}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const cars = [{
  car: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}];

const key = cars.map((val) => `${val.car}|${val.year}`)[0]

console.log([{cars, key}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const cars = [{
  car: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}];

const output = cars.map((prop) => {
  return {
    cars: [{
      car: prop.car,
      year: prop.year,
    }],
    key: `${prop.car}|${prop.year}`,
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in a one-liner, just because it's possible:

```js
const cars = [{
  car: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}];

const result = cars.map((val) => ({cars: [val], key: `${val.car}|${val.year}`}));

console.log(result);
```

Note, however, that if you copy `val` directly, it still references the original object, which means that changes to the `cars` array would change the result array's data as well.